# Update trigger for SQL Server linked server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, linked-server, distributed-transactions

Update trigger doesn't work while using SQL Server linked server.

I created a linked server on my local SQL Server. I can query this linked server (`SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT` etc.) from my local machine.

I create an UPDATE trigger one of my local tables:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_trg]
ON [myLocalDB].[dbo].[localTable]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE [192.168.3.102].[myRemoteDB].[dbo].[remoteTable] 
    SET lastTime = (SELECT lastTime FROM myLocalDB.dbo.localTable)    
    /* I wrote this way because lastTime = myLocalDB.dbo.localTable.lastTime didn't work */
    WHERE id = 1
END
```

But this trigger didn't work despite I can query my linked server database as I mentioned.

I get an error:

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "192.168.3.102" was unable to begin a distributed transaction.

I have enabled "Distributed Transaction Coordinator" and checked security settings of Local DTC properties on both machines.

This time my `UPDATE` query on local machine keeps executing query... and doesn't return any message or error.

Please help if anyone has faced this issue before (and solved it).

Comment: Did you try to Set "enable promotion of distributed transaction for RPC" for the linked server to False?

Comment: @siggemannen, yeah I tried both false and true.

Comment: I don't know, but your trigger has a fatal flaw, it assumes there is exactly one row in `inserted`. You need to join it `UPDATE r SET lastTime = i.lastTime
FROM [192.168.3.102].[myRemoteDB].[dbo].[remoteTable] r JOIN inserted i ON i.id = r.id;`

Comment: @Charlieface yeah I know. But this trigger works when I apply it to my local table. This shows it is a linked-server issue, not trigger syntax issue.

Comment: Hmm. interesting. I really don't like DTC, you can first get the local date into a variable, and then build a `EXEC('update...') AT remoteServer` string to do all the work at the remote server

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks later I started researching the problem again. I think I found the answer. So, **I created MS DTC rule in Windows Firewall settings.**

- In Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, select  Inbound Rules and click New Rule in the action pane.
- On the Rule Type page click Predefined, click Distributed Transaction Coordinator, and click Next.
- On the Predefined Rules page, select all rules for Distributed Transaction Coordinator (RPC-EPMAP), Distributed Transaction Coordinator (RPC), Distributed Transaction Coordinator (TCP-In), and click Next.
- On the Action page, select Allow the connection, and click Finish.

Then my Update Trigger worked.